# Cannot convert from uint32_t* to LPDWORD

Tags: c++, winapi, casting

I'm trying to call the Windows API function `GetExitCodeProcess` which takes a `LPDWORD` as its second parameter.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `LPDWORD` is a pointer to an unsigned 32-bit value. So I tried to pass a `uint32_t*`, but the compiler (MSVC 11.0) is not happy with it:

> error C2664: 'GetExitCodeProcess' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'uint32_t *' to 'LPDWORD'

Also a `static_cast` does not help. Why is that? And is it safe to use a `reinterpret_cast` in this case?

Comment: Why not use a `DWORD` then just assign back to your `uint32_t`?

Comment: DWORD is unsigned long, which is not the same as unsigned int

Comment: @stijn: MSDN says `DWORD` is "A 32-bit unsigned integer". So is `uint32_t`. So what's the difference?

Comment: @Chad: I guess I could do that (right now I'm using `reinterpret_cast` as a workaround). But I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: The difference is that a pointer to an unsigned int is different to a pointer to an unsigned long.

Comment: Find the definition of LPDWORD in the Windows header file and see how it is actually defined (documentation lies sometimes).   You might be able to just hover your mouse over it and get the answer.

Comment: DWORD means `DOUBLE WORD`, WORD is the meaning of 2 BYTES which make up a WORD together and two WORDS make up a `DOUBLE WORD` so there is no way `DWORD` can be a unsigned long which is `(64 bits)` it will always mean `(32 bits)` aka unsigned int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx#DWORD):

> **DWORD**
>
> A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295 decimal.
>   This type is declared in IntSafe.h as follows:
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned long DWORD;
> ```

So, `LPDWORD` is `unsigned long int*`. But you are trying to pass `unsigned int*`. I know that the types point to variables that are the same size, but the pointer types are not compatible.

The solution is to declare a variable of type `DWORD`, and pass the address of that variable. Something like this:

```
DWORD dwExitCode;
if (!GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &dwExitCode))
{
    // deal with error
}
uint32_t ExitCode = dwExitCode;
```

Comment: I noticed that `DWORD` is defined as `unsigned long` but I didn't expect that the compiler treats an `unsinged long` and an `unsigned int` differently, since they have the same size. - Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Aside: I'm not questioning why you want to store the exit code in a `uint32_t`. Personally, I wonder why you don't just use `DWORD`.

Comment: It's the pointer types that are treated differently. You can assign from int to long and vice versa. But not for `int*` and `long*`.

Comment: I'm writing a function that starts a process, waits until that process is finished, and then returns its exit code. I'm going to implement that function for Windows and for Linux with the same interface. That's why I'm not using the Windows specific typedefs in the signature of my function (but I can use your solution in the Windows implementation, of course).

Comment: @RobertHegner *since they have the same size* just think of it this way, for example: in a 32bit process a 32 bit float and a pointer to a class are also the same size, yet the compiler obviously will obviously prohibit you from eg assigning one to the other. Size doesn;t matter here, type does.